# Sorting favorites by newest still shows last activity instead of creation date

Tags: bug, profile-page, bookmarks, sorting, timestamps

- When questions are [sorted by "active"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active), the timestamps and usernames refer to last activity.
- When questions are [sorted by "newest"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), the timestamps and usernames refer to creation.

This makes sense: if I'm sorting by newest, this means I'm interested in the creation dates, not in last activity.

But the list of favorites in user profile does not follow this logic. Sorting it by newest still displays the timestamps and usernames referring to last activity on the question:

[image: favs]

This is inconsistent with the behavior of /questions page, and also undesirable: if I wanted to know about activity, I would be on the "active" tab.

Comment: +1 This behavior is on profile's 'questions' tab too... and possibly other tab too... Please see my question: [Confusion about Date/Time shown on profile's activity questions tab...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260824/confusion-about-date-time-shown-on-profiles-activity-questions-tab-sorted-by-n)